# Jquery Slide messing up other div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sight problem with jquery slide at the moment I have atached a code snippet that will show you the problem

Right now when I click the wrapper3head to drop down the wrapper 3 information it push 3 of the pad shapes down

My problem is that the 2 wrappers are now where near the pad but it still pushes them down

I am looking for help to get the 3 pad shapes to stay when I click the wrapper3head

if you run the snippet you will see what I mean just click the choose memory style div

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wrapper3head").click(function(){
    $("#wrapper3").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    });
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Informationhead").click(function(){
    $("#Information").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


.wrapper2{
  position: relative;
  width: 652px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.wrapper3head{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align:center;
  float:right;
  margin-right:1%;
}

.wrapper3{
  position: relative;
  width: 185px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:none;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  text-align:center;
  float:right;
  margin-right:1%;
}

.Informationhead{
  position: relative;
  width: 652px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align:center;
}

.Information{
  position: relative;
  width: 635px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:none;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  text-align:center;
}

.back {
  position: relative;
  width: 648px;
  height: 648px;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  border:3.5px ridge white;
  border-radius: 310px;
}

.pad {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.shape1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  border:2.5px groove white;
  
}

.shape2 {
  float: left;
  border-top-right-radius: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  clear: right;
  border:2.5px groove white;
  position: relative;
}

.shape3 {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  clear: left;
  border:2.5px groove white;
}

.shape4 {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  border:2.5px groove white;
}

.Timer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 195px;
  left: 195px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 125px;
  border:2.5px solid White;
  z-index: 10;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <br />
 <center><img src="Media/GroupLogo1.png" alt="Logo" height="200" width="250"></center>
 <br />
 
 <div class="Informationhead"id="Informationhead">Information</div>
 <div class="Information"id="Information">
 <p>Hello</p>
 </div>

 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="wrapper3head"id="wrapper3head">Choose Your Memory Style</div>
 <br />
 <br />
 <div class="wrapper3"id="wrapper3">
 <p>Do You Want Sound ?</p>
 <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="sound">Yes
    <p>Do You want Flashes ?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="flash">Yes
    <p>Do You want Text ?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="text">Yes
 </div>
 
  <div class="back">
   <div class="pad shape1" data-pad="1">
    <audio preload="auto" class="sound1">
     <source src="Media/sounds/mp3/sounds_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
     <source src="Media/sounds/ogg/sounds_01.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
   </div>
   <div class="pad shape2" data-pad="2">
    <audio preload="auto" class="sound2">
     <source src="Media/sounds/mp3/sounds_02.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg"/>
     <source src="Media/sounds/ogg/sounds_02.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
   </div>
      <div class="Timer">
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
            <center><p><b><i>Time starts when you click start</i></b></p></center> 
   </div>
   
   <div class="pad shape3" data-pad="3">
    <audio preload="auto" class="sound3">
     <source src="Media/sounds/mp3/sounds_03.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
     <source src="Media/sounds/ogg/sounds_03.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
   </div>
   <div class="pad shape4" data-pad="4">
    <audio preload="auto" class="sound4">
     <source src="Media/sounds/mp3/sounds_04.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
     <source src="Media/sounds/ogg/sounds_04.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the dropdown has a `relative` position. You will need to give it an `absolute` position so that it doesn't affect any other elements on the page once it opens. Adding this CSS to your stylesheet will fix the problem:

```
.wrapper3 {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0px;
}
```

---

Here's a working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrapper3head").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper3").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Informationhead").click(function() {
    $("#Information").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.wrapper2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 652px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.wrapper3head {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.wrapper3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 185px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.Informationhead {
  position: relative;
  width: 652px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.Information {
  position: relative;
  width: 635px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  border: 5px groove #8E2B2B;
  text-align: center;
}
.back {
  position: relative;
  width: 648px;
  height: 648px;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 3.5px ridge white;
  border-radius: 310px;
}
.pad {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.shape1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2.5px groove white;
}
.shape2 {
  float: left;
  border-top-right-radius: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  clear: right;
  border: 2.5px groove white;
  position: relative;
}
.shape3 {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  clear: left;
  border: 2.5px groove white;
}
.shape4 {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2.5px groove white;
}
.Timer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 195px;
  left: 195px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 125px;
  border: 2.5px solid White;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <br />
  <center>
    <img src="Media/GroupLogo1.png" alt="Logo" height="200" width="250">
  </center>
  <br />

  <div class="Informationhead" id="Informationhead">Information</div>
  <div class="Information" id="Information">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper3head" id="wrapper3head">Choose Your Memory Style</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="wrapper3" id="wrapper3">
      <p>Do You Want Sound ?</p>
      <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="sound">Yes
      <p>Do You want Flashes ?</p>
      <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="flash">Yes
      <p>Do You want Text ?</p>
      <input type="checkbox" value="No" style="color: Black;" id="text">Yes
    </div>

    <div class="back">
      <div class="pad shape1" data-pad="1">
        <audio preload="auto" class="sound1">
          <source src="Media/sounds/mp3/sounds_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
          <source src="Media/sounds/ogg/sounds_01.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        </audio>
      </div>
      <div class="pad shape2" data-pad="2">
        <audio preload="auto" class="sound2">
          <source src="Media/sounds/mp3/sounds_02.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
          <source src="Media/sounds/ogg/sounds_02.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        </audio>
      </div>
      <div class="Timer">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <center>
          <p><b><i>Time starts when you click start</i></b>
          </p>
        </center>
      </div>

      <div class="pad shape3" data-pad="3">
        <audio preload="auto" class="sound3">
          <source src="Media/sounds/mp3/sounds_03.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
          <source src="Media/sounds/ogg/sounds_03.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        </audio>
      </div>
      <div class="pad shape4" data-pad="4">
        <audio preload="auto" class="sound4">
          <source src="Media/sounds/mp3/sounds_04.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
          <source src="Media/sounds/ogg/sounds_04.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        </audio>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```